# How do I capture HTTP outgoing requests on my client?

Tags: c#, http

I have a C# application and I want to capture outgoing http requests that have been made through the application (I can also identify that it was from the app because I have a specific server name).
When searching on the web all I could find was capturing incoming requests (so the code is on the server side) with TcpListener and HttpListener.
But the code must be client side so it must be outgoing requests.
And I cannot use any third party libraries (like FiddlerCore for example).
So I'm really looking for a code sample to start from.

Comment: What is your client application? WPF? How does it send requests to your server?

Comment: Yes it's wpf. I'm also using ESRI's feature layer which sends HTTP requests to the arcgis web server. I want to catch these requests before they are sent and send them after I'm done

Comment: If your wpf invokes ESRI's feature, which constructs and sends the http requests, then I am afraid you are out of luck, unless you have a control of the ESRI's request process.

Comment: If you are using `HttpClient` you can pass in a custom message handler and in there log the requests and responses.

Comment: @StephenZeng so there is no way to capture outgoing http requests on a machine unless I created those HTTP requests?

Comment: @Krumelur Unfortunately, I am not the one creating the requests

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to store the request or just access it for debugging? 
If you are going after debugging, then you can use Fiddler. Fiddler is an HTTP debugging proxy server application. And if you are planning to modify or read data in the request or the response you can use [HTTPRequestWrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestwrapper(v=vs.110).aspx) and  [HTTPResponseWrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsewrapper(v=vs.110).aspx) to access.

Comment: I want to access it through the code. So I can't use fiddler. Iwant to catch the request, do a few checks and send it

Comment: I think OP wants to check something in the request before it is sent out from the client app.

Comment: you can use the [HTTPRequestWrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestwrapper(v=vs.110).aspx)
same for [HTTPResponseWrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsewrapper(v=vs.110).aspx)
by just calling Request object or Response in you code

Comment: I don't have access to the original HTTPRequest. How should I capture it with those classes?

Comment: Have you tried including System.Web namespace to your class ?

Comment: Do you have a sample code how to access requests that weren't made by me?

Comment: For me i usually write `Request.Headers` simply as that

Comment: or `Request.Cookies` or just `Request`